# Managing multiple mobile apps for each country store

Tags: android, ios, mobile-development

We have a mobile app that is our main product.

We need to provide a different price (not just currency conversion) for it for each country store. As we found out (please let me know if this is wrong), the only way to do this is to upload the app separately on each country store (i.e. separate apps).

Is there an easy way to manage these uploads to the 10+ stores we're targeting. By managing I mean uploading the release itself on all needed country stores as well as monitoring all apps KPIs like number of installs.

Comment: zaph thanks a lot.
I already upvoted @Daniele 's answer but didn't accept it yet. I need an answer for iOS.

Answer (score 1):

When you upload an app in your Google Play Dev Console, click in Prices and Distribution form into the left menu, and then in Automatic conversion price form check "Overwrite existing prices". Now you can personalize your price by country.

Comment: Amazing. Thanks.  What about apple's app store?